# How to check HttpURLConnection closed or not in java

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

How to check `HttpURLConnection` closed or not in Java.

```
HttpURLConnection connection;
InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
```

What is the different between :

1. `inputStream.close();`
2. `connection.disconnect();`

What will happen try to close or disconnect connection.  If connection already closed or disconnected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If client called HttpURLConnection.getInputSteam().close(), the later call to HttpURLConnection.disconnect() will NOT close the Socket. i.e. The Socket is reused (cached)

If client does not call close(), call to disconnect() will close the InputSteam and close the Socket.

So in order to reuse the Socket, just call InputStream close(). Do not call HttpURLConnection disconnect().

Comment: Remember to call close() in a finally block, as if you don't, then that connection cannot be reused, and it'll lead to resource leaks.